# shortening url to cms

Tags: shortcuts

Hi
We have a CMS application that lets people create websites under our domain.
The system was built a few years ago and it used a method that transfers parameters such as website id, folder code and more using the url. this method created a giant url for every item in the website

For example:
My domain is www.domain.com
A users website on my domain is www.domain.com/user
and every time that a user enters his website he gets a link like this
www.domain.com/page.aspx?code=blablasdsdsdsdsds&folder=blablablablablabla and more.

We are trying to reduce the string size in the url.
What are our options? can we show the user one url like a virtual one and still work the same with the old url?
We are trying to locate a solution that wont make us rewrite our entire application.

the application is built in c# and the web server is iis 6.
Thanks

Comment: Actual programming questions should go on Stack Overflow, Server setup questions should go on Server Fault and web site operational questions should go on Webmasters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to consider URL Rewrite (or friendly URL) techniques. IIS6 could be a little tricky though.

You can find lots of resource just by google-ing.

http://www.google.com/search?q=url+rewrite+asp.net

An example can be found in this SO post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2262/asp-net-url-rewriting

Answer (score 0):

You can refer following article:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx

One of my friend has used similar solution which is working great.

Gaurav Maniar MCP | MCSE | MCST | MCITP | ITILv3 Certified